# Confused betewen reducers and dispatchers concerning actions

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, redux

I'm a bit confused about reducers and dispatchers.
Both will get actions as a parameter, but it doesn't mean that my dispatchers' actions are the same of my reducers actions, right?

Let say I have an action called **fetchData**, that action will be dispatch but won't reach the reducer since it doesn't modify the state.

All tutorials I read about redux, teach to set all the actions in one place.
I think we should have **reducersActions** and **dispatchersActions**.

Am I missing something?

Comment: they should be the same and every action will hit all reducers... doesn't mean it will modify the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, Breaking actions as `reducersActions` and `dispatchersAction`can be done but it is not a standard convention.

When you define an action, basically it revolves around an entity (for which you define a state and maintain it later) . The naming conventions of actions should clarify the intention of it's existence, and it varies as discussed [here](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#priority-c-rules-recommended).

So keeping action at one place but with proper naming (which reflects the intention) of action should be good enough to understand whether its a call to reducer (which will only return new state) or dispatcher (which will fan out more actions).

In your example of **fetchData** , there is no clarity of its purpose. Focus on states, and then start creating actions. Things will automatically fall into place.